# Is this a valid transformation?

Tags: convex-optimization

I have the following objective:

\begin{equation}
\max_{\mathcal{I}} \sum_{m=1}^{M}w_m\sum_{n \in N_m}^{ }I_{m}^{n}
\end{equation}

subject to some constraints, beside tha fact that the variables $I_{m}^{n} \in \mathcal{I}$ and $I_{m}^{n} \geq 0$ and $I_{m}^{n} \leq I_{max}$ and $w_m$ are some positive scalars.

I was thinking of doing the following transformation which will be useful later

\begin{align}
\max_{\mathcal{I}}& \sum_{m=1}^{M}w_m\sum_{n \in N_m}^{ }I_{m}^{n} \nonumber \\ 
= \min_{\mathcal{I}}& \left(\sum_{m=1}^{M}w_m\sum_{n \in N_m}^{ }I_{m}^{n} \right )^{-1} \nonumber \\ 
\end{align}

then rewrite as:

\begin{align}
&\min_{t \geq 0} ~t^{-1} \nonumber \\ 
&\text{subject}~\text{to} \nonumber \\ 
\sum_{m=1}^{M}w_m&\sum_{n \in N_m}^{ }I_{m}^{n} \leq t \nonumber \\ 
\end{align}

Is this a valid transformation ?

Answer (score 0):

well after some thinking i guess it is not valid because the new objective can be equivalently written as

\begin{equation} 
\max_{t \geq 0} t
\end{equation}

which results in $t=\infty $ which leads to the constraint being

\begin{equation} 
\sum_{m=1}^{M}w_m\sum_{n \in N_m}^{ }I_{m}^{n} \leq \infty
\end{equation}